# E4: Synchronization for caching with progressmonitor from multiple async calls

Tags: user-interface, concurrency, rcp, e4

We cache some objects from a database and frequently use them within the GUI of our Eclipse RCP application.
They are accessed in a renderer, so the calls are async.

Before we access the objects, we do a quick up-to-date check.
If new data is available, it is loaded and the user sees a progressmonitor.

```
boolean upToDate = isDatabaseUptoDate();
if(!upToDate) {
    cacheData(); //this can take a while and is done with a progressmonitor
}
```

Now, the problem is that if we fork the progressmonitor, the next async call will start execution and call the same method. But during the data caching, everything else must wait.

So the first idea was to use a semaphore, but that will always run into a deadlock, because the progressmonitor can never finish its execution if the GUI thread blocks with the semaphore.

What would be  the right approach here?

Comment: Personally I would use a Job with a Scheduling Rule that will prevent multiple jobs running at one

Comment: @greg-449 I guess that would add quite some performance impact? The method is called really quite often. I would say up to 100 times per second.

Comment: At that sort of rate a progress monitor is also a significant overhead. I would just use the standard Java thread classes in java.util.concurrent maybe using something like BlockingQueue to queue request to the threads or an ExecutorService and Future

Comment: Of course - the progressmonitor will not be createed 100 times per second. Only in rare cases when an update is required. The problem is, that the up-to-date check must not be done during the caching. That means that it needs to be included in the "locked" scope. I just tried it though with a job and it even seems to be performant enough. But it feels kind of wrong...

Comment: What about an isUpdating() method?
if(!isUpdating()){
boolean upToDate = isDatabaseUptoDate();
if(!upToDate) {
    cacheData(); //this can take a while and is done with a progressmonitor
}}

Comment: @Yaza Unfortunately this would only prevent from douplicate calls to the caching method. We would then return immediately from the call and allow access to a not completed cache. This must be prevented as well. So in short: all calls to this method must not return until the cache is clean.

Comment: Then wait for the update to complete before returning: